# I want to open a netcat connection and keep sending some text forever

Tags: bash, netcat

```
echo " The NC send commands  on port 2612"
while :
do
echo "hello " | nc -q -1  <some IP> 2612 
done
```

I want open a netcat session forever, and that is been achived by -q -1.

How can I send "hello" on the same channed in every 20 second.

my earlier script was as following, but that opens nc connection every time.
What I really want is to open connection once and send "echo hello" evey 20 sec.

```
while :
do
echo "hello " | nc  192.168.100.161 2612 
sleep 20 
done
```

Answer (score 5):

```
while echo "hello"; do
  sleep 20
done | nc -q 192.168.100.161 2612
```

Note that we moved the `echo` into the condition of the loop, so that we stop trying to run it if `nc` exits (causing the `echo`s to fail).

---

If you want to be able to retain state (for instance, a counter) from inside the loop and access it after the pipeline exited, then things need to change a bit further:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- process substitutions aren't part of POSIX sh

count=0
while echo "hello"; do
  (( ++count ))
  sleep 20
done > >(nc -q 192.168.100.161 2612)

echo "Ran $count loops before exiting" >&2
```

There, the redirection is done as a *process substitution*, and the loop takes place inside the same shell instance that continues after it exits. See [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) for more details on this problem and solution.

Comment: It is starting a new nc process, I do not want that.                                   $ ps -f | grep 'nc'
      3232  2354  0 13:41 pts/14   00:00:00 grep --color=auto nc
$ ps -f | grep 'nc'
    3234  2354  0 13:42 pts/14   00:00:00 grep --color=auto nc
$ ps -f | grep 'nc'
     3236  2354  0 13:42 pts/14   00:00:00 grep --color=auto nc
 ps -f | grep 'nc'
   3238  2354  0 13:42 pts/14   00:00:00 grep --color=auto nc
 ps -f | grep 'nc'
   3240  2354  0 13:42 pts/14   00:00:00 grep --color=auto nc

Comment: **One** new `nc` process, not one per loop. If you want to show otherwise, btw, use something that actually lets you represent multi-line pastes properly. https://gist.github.com/ is a good choice.

Comment: @astha, btw, run the script with `PS4=':${LINENO}+' bash -x scriptname` -- it'll show every process it runs, so if it starts `nc` more than once, it'll show more than once in the log. I'd accept that as much more convincing evidence than output of `ps`.

Comment: Thank you and sorry about almost unreadable multiline paste. That is what  happens when I skip lunch :)

Comment: -q didn't work for me but otherwise great solution

Comment: @9Guy There are a lot of different programs called "nc"; can't cover all of 'em. (The GNU version and the nmap version are the two that come to front-of-mind first, but I don't think either of those was the original; personally, these days I skip 'em all and use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/)).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it kept asking for an integer argument for -q, from the manpage it was the debian port, so idk. It was for a ctf so i've solved it and moved on. Thanks for the link though!